# Change schemas' structure in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, multi-tenant

I have a Postgres database with some schemas (all have the same structure), I want to know if there is the possibility to change the structure (Table names, new columns etc) for all the schemas in the same database. Is it possible or what's the purpose of the schemas in a database?

Thanks.

Comment: http://youtu.be/ymb9gsl_x1U

Comment: Sorry - hit enter by mistake.  The schema describes the overall organization of the database and how all the tables inside the database relate (or don't relate) to each other.  Tables can be altered, but it's hard to give a comprehensive answer without more specific information.  This video might help explain how schemas and tables work.  http://youtu.be/ymb9gsl_x1U  If you want to go more in depth, Stanford University offers a database class online for free.  https://class.stanford.edu/courses/Engineering/db/2014_1/about

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to focus on the second half of your question, because I *think* it'll answer the first half (and I'm not sure I *understand* the first half).

> **what's the purpose** of the schemas in a database?

---

This confused me when I first switched from MySQL to PostgreSQL. A Postgres schema is essentially the same as a MySQL database. In fact, according to the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_schema):

> In MySQL, physically, a ***schema*** is synonymous with a ***database***.

---

That begs the question of what is a PostgreSQL database, then? From the [PostgreSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/manage-ag-overview.html):

> More accurately, a database is a collection of schemas and the schemas contain the tables, functions, etc. So the full hierarchy is: server, database, schema, table (or some other kind of object, such as a function).

---

So a PostgreSQL database is essentially a collection of schemas? Seems kind of pointless, why do we need that step in the hierarchy? Let's take a look at the docs for a [PostgreSQL schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html):

> A PostgreSQL database cluster contains one or more named databases. Users and groups of users are shared across the entire cluster, but no other data is shared across databases. Any given client connection to the server can access only the data in a single database, the one specified in the connection request.
>
> A database contains one or more named *schemas*, which in turn contain tables. Schemas also contain other kinds of named objects, including data types, functions, and operators. The same object name can be used in different schemas without conflict; for example, both `schema1` and `myschema` can contain tables named `mytable`. Unlike databases, schemas are not rigidly separated: a user can access objects in any of the schemas in the database he is connected to, if he has privileges to do so.

---

So, in PostgreSQL, a schema contains tables, functions, etc. And a database manages user/group connectivity and access/roles to specific clusters of schemas. Typically, I work under one database and have information broken into schemas to segment information.

Comment: The SQL standard defines two levels of "namespaces": catalogs and schemas. A "catalog" can contain multiple "schemas". A Postgres "database" maps (to a certain extent) to the concept of a catalog in the SQL standard. It's essentially the same way as SQL Server manages databases and schemas. Other DBMS (e.g. H2, HSQLDB) have similar two-level namespaces.

Comment: Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name, didn't know that and it is very useful to my answer :)